# Sublime Text 2: Error trying to parse settings

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

How do I fix this error?

> Error trying to parse settings: No data in ~/Library/Application
>   Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/JavaScript.sublime-settings:1:1

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Most likely you or something has created an empty file in your User config directory.

The config files must be valid JSON. The file in the question is empty and is not JSON.

Try deleting the file or get a fixed version from somewhere (not sure for what the file is being used for)

Comment: Cool thanks Mikko thats what I suspected.

To fix I typed into terminal:

sudo vim ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/User/JavaScript.sublime-settings

And added {} to the file. I guess I prob could have deleted the file as well.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `sudo` for files residing in your own home directory - they should be always writable by you

Comment: You could also have accessed the file via the ST2 gui: Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax-specific - User.

Answer (score 0):

Default installs c: / Program Files / Sublime Text 2

Change by:  c: / Program Files / Sublime Text

I do not know why, but it works .. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Sublime Text 3 (Build 3059):**

My **JSON.sublime-settings** was containing some XML-structure, no JSON.

Here the previous content of my file:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>JSON String</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>meta.structure.dictionary.json string.quoted.double.json</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#E6DB74</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I replaced it with the default content from [SublimePrettyJson](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson):

```
{
    "use_entire_file_if_no_selection" : true,
    "indent" : 2,
    "sort_keys" : false,
    "ensure_ascii" : false
}
```

This solved the problem for me. No more annoying error message. 
OS: Windows 7.

On my Ubuntu machines I never had this error, also not on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to ../Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/ location and delete JavaScript.sublime-settings:1:1 file which has been created by you or any process must have created that.This would surely work.