# Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:1:1

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I know there are at least 2 other questions like this on SO but none of those answers are working for me.

I'm trying to customize my user settings on Sublime Text 2 (mac) but when I go to save it I get the error listed below.

Here are my settings.

```
{
  "caret_style": "phase",
  "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme",
  "default_encoding": "UTF-8 with BOM",
  "font_size": 15,
  "highlight_line": true,
  "highlight_modified_tabs": true,
  "ignored_packages": [
    "Vintage"
  ],
  "line_padding_bottom": 4,
  "line_padding_top": 0,
  "wide_caret": true
}
```

Here's the error:

Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:1:1

The answers listed on [Sublime Text 2: Error trying to parse settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360696/sublime-text-2-error-trying-to-parse-settings) and on [Error trying to parse settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009643/error-trying-to-parse-settings) do not help at all.

Comment: Are you sure that's the file that is giving you errors? The JSON in it is valid according to JSONlint,com but the error message you're reporting says that it's broken at line 1, character 1 which it clearly is not.

Comment: Yes. Sublime text won't show any of my custom settings and when I try to edit the file it displays the error. Also when I open a new instance of Sublime it will display the error